# Type '()' cannot conform to 'AttributedStringProtocol'

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have a function inside my main model viewer, with the following code:

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func getUserUsername() {
        if let u = User.current {
            username =  u.username ?? ""
        } else {
            username = ""
        }
        log.info("\n : (MainViewModel: 193) - Set the 'Username' as: \(self.username.isEmpty ? "N/A" : self.username).")
        print("")
    }
}
```

Then inside a View, I have the following code:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
   var body: some View {
      @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel

      Text("User: " + model.getUserUsername())
   }
}
```

The issue is that it's throwing a `Type '()' cannot conform to 'AttributedStringProtocol'` error - I want to be able to just output the username for debugging purposes.

Comment: Missing `return username`(or whatever you want to return) inside `getUserUsername()`?

Comment: It's not that, I can get the username when used inside another function, but just can't output it using `Text()` - but if I pass a `return username` I get the following error: `Unexpected non-void return value in void function`

Comment: You have to declare the function return type if you gonna return something

Comment: Make it `func getUserUsername () -> String` for example

Comment: Looks like that ended up working out perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the return type of your function just like below code.

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func getUserUsername() -> String {
        if let u = User.current {
            username =  u.username ?? ""
        } else {
            username = ""
        }
        log.info("\n : (MainViewModel: 193) - Set the 'Username' as: \(self.username.isEmpty ? "N/A" : self.username).")
        print("")
        return username

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare the variable     @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel above the var body: some View { Like below:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model: MainViewModel
   var body: some View {
  Text("User: " + model.getUserUsername())
```

}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).